# Bash to Python convertion

Tags: python, bash, shell

Want to convert the below shell code into python.

```
$line = ddtest-7.0
find . -name "*.json" -exec grep -l "project_name.*\"$line\"" {} \; | grep -vw project
```

This code will do the below functions:

1). It will search for all json files in the current directory(includes subdirectory)

2). It will open each json file, and search for "project_name.*\"$line\"( "projectname": "ddtest-7.0",), if it is present in file . it will store the json file name with path.

3). It will remove the json file from the project directory(grep -vw project)

Output:

```
./product/ddtest/7.0/product-info.json
```

Can someone help to covert this into python (version 2.7).

Comment: Please attempt it first and let us know which part doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Show what you have tried and researched so far.  By the way, your first line of `bash` is invalid.  Don't use the `$` unary operator on the left-side of an assignment and spaces around the `=` are not allowed.

Comment: Take a browse through this:  http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/index.html

Answer (score 2):

From Python 3.5 onwards you can do something like this:

```
import glob
list(glob.iglob('**/project_name.*/ddtest-7.0/**/*.json', recursive=True))
```

Comment: Thanks.

But , I am using python 2.7

Comment: Then you should switch, but you can do a similar filtering manually using `os.walk`.

Comment: I am new to shell and python. can you please mention the code here?

Comment: Something like this: `[filtered for filtered in [(entry[0], [f for f in entry[2] if '.json' in f]) for entry in os.walk(os.getcwd()) if 'ddtest-7.0' in entry[0]] if filtered[1]]`